# Calculator App using Radio Groups and Buttons

Tags: java, android

I am getting a lot of errors on declaring my Variables from the widgets I am using. Also my if statement isn't working. I am new to all this so it could be a lot of synthetic issues.

Looked on you Tube for answers a long with google.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    TextView Directions;
    TextView Results;
    EditText Num1;
    EditText Num2;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton Add;
    RadioButton Subtract;
    RadioButton Multiple;
    RadioButton Divide;
    Button Cal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView = findViewById(textView);
        TextView = findViewById(Directions);
        TextView = findViewById(Results);
        EditText = findViewById(Num1);
        EditText = findViewById(Num2);
        RadioGroup = findViewById(radioGroup);
        RadioButton = findViewById(Add);
        RadioButton = findViewById(Subtract);
        RadioButton = findViewById(Multiple);
        RadioButton = findViewById(Divide);
        Button = findViewById(Cal);

        Directions.setText("Please enter two numbers and than select Add, Subtract, Multiple or Divide. Than click Calculate");
        Results.setText("0");


    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Switch(view.getId()){
            case (R.id.Add:)
                if (Add == onClick(View);
                    Results = Num1+Num2;
                    Results.setText((CharSequence) Results);


                if (Subtract == onClick();
                    Results = Num1-Num2;
                    Results.setText((CharSequence) Results);

                if (Multiple ==(onClick();
                    Results = Num1*Num2;
                    Results.setText((CharSequence) Results);

                if (Divide == (onClick();
                    Results = Num1/Num2;
                    Results.setText((CharSequence) Results);

                else
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text:"Invalid option"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                toast.show();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable declaration is incorrect.

The correct format to declare **TextView** is:

```
TextView var1 

var1 = findViewById(R.id.textView)
```

Over here `var1` is the variable name and `textView` is the id of the TextView

Similarly for the components as well.

So, please correct your variable declaration and initialization.